# Is SSL Support compiled into openldap binaries for RHEL?

Tags: openldap

Is SSL Support compiled into openldap binaries for RHEL5? Also is there any command to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldd(1)` will show you the libraries a binary was linked against. `rpm -q --requires <package name>` will show you the other packages required by a given package. They won't give you definitive answers (nothing short of actually *trying* it out will), but they are very big indicators.